# foreach doesn't print altered array properly

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to print an array using **foreach** and while printing, if a certain $key comes up, I want to make changes to the array. Problem is, even though the array gets changed, the changes do not get printed.

In the example below, you will find:

- function I use to change the array;
- an array first printed with no changed;
- then echo print-out in with changes during the process - all using foreach;
- another print-out of the same table, but this time with changes.

  ```
  <?php

  function insert_before_key($array, $key, $data = NULL){
      if (($offset = array_search($key, array_keys($array))) === false){
          $offset = count($array); 
      }
      return array_merge(array_slice($array, 0, $offset), (array) $data, array_slice($array, $offset));
  }

  $array = array(
      "no_color"  =>  "blank",
      "color1"    =>  "red",
      "color2"    =>  "green",
      "color3"    =>  "blue",
      );

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($array);
  echo "</pre>";

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
      echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
      if ($key === "color1"){
          $array = insert_before_key($array, "color2", array("color1.5" => "yellow"));
      }
  }

  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($array);
  echo "</pre>";

  echo "<br />";

  ?>
  ```

Note that the new $key is to jump in **AFTER** current $key, so I would expect it to come up.
Any idea why this happens ?

**EDIT:**

Played a bit more with foreach and I think it must be caching the keys or something...

```
    <?php
    $test_array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

    foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 5){$test_array[7] = $test_array[7]+1;}
        echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
    }

    print_r($test_array);
    ?>
```

The above will display UNCHANGED echo, but CHANGED print_r.

Comment: I think that `insert_before_key` function isn't meant for associative arrays...

Comment: Looking at your code, if you need to "insert" because you want the array elements to be ordered by its keys, why don't you just append the new element(s) and ksort() the array? 'no_color' will be placed at the end but color1.5 will be placed between color1 and color2 (I think :-p)

Comment: @rlatief: This is just a simple example to show what I mean, but the real code has different keys. ksort will mix everything and the array has to stay how it originally was (apart from the added key).
Also, this is the only way I know to add a key into an associative array. If you know better please share :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the manual: "As foreach relies on the internal array pointer, changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior." http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

You shouldn't modify an array you're looping over.

Answer (score 3):

So during iteration you are trying to change the value of the item being iterated

```
foreach($array ...)
{
    change $array
}
```

Use a copy of $array inside the iteration

```
 $array2 = $array
 foreach($array ...)
{
    change $array2
}
```

Comment: But I need the new key displayed as well if added.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep it simple. Something tells me however that you're fixing effects of a problem here and not its source.

```
$array = array(
    "no_color"  =>  "blank",
    "color1"    =>  "red",
    "color2"    =>  "green",
    "color3"    =>  "blue",
);

$temp_array = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $temp_array[$key] = $value;
    echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br />";
    if ($key == 'color1') {
        $key_add = 'color1.5';
        $value_add = 'yellow';
        $temp_array[$key_add] = $value_add;
        echo $key_add . ": " . $value_add . "<br />";
    }
}

$array = $temp_array;
```